# Autolayout with multiple containerView's of dynamic heigth in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, storyboard, uicontainerview

I have been exploding my head on this one for weeks. I knew it was time to ask you guys after trying every `NSLayoutConstraint` combination possible:)

My MainViewController has several parts for news, friends, profile and etc working like a summary page for the user's activities. I want to implement these different parts as separate `ViewController`s since otherwise it would be mixing apples and pears. Right? And obviously these need to go inside a `UIScrollView` because they will be longer than the screen height.

One thing which makes everything harder is that these `childViewController`s' heights are of variable length and decided at runtime according to their content downloaded from the server.

Can you lead me to the right strategy on how to architect this design? I want to use storyboard. If not possible, I can do all it in the code too. I believe the tricky part is to set the right constraints of `MainViewController`'s subviews(`UIScrollView`, `UIView`, `UIContainerView`) and somehow passing the `ChildViewController`s height in an appropriate place.

And I am also amazed how little information there is on this subject. I always thought this kind of a design must be pretty popular in apps.

Comment: I think you should set fixed height constraint on those views, and change the constant value of that constraint according to your needs.

Comment: Sounds like you need UIStackView. It automatically sizes content based on their intrinsic size, and even animates changes. You can put it inside a UIScrollView, too.

Comment: @almas So you are saying I should create IBOutlet height constraints for childVCs (do they need to be placeholder constraints?) and where will I update the constraints? Inside childVC's server call?

Comment: @Clafou I will look in to `UIStackView`s after your comment. But since it is not supported before iOS 9.0, it is my last resort for now

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with using `UIScrollView` I would in almost 99% of cases not recommend them. They are hard to use with auto-layout and they can easily be broken by minor changes. They're also super annoying to use in IB as you can't scroll its contents.

For this design I would rather use a `UITableView` with static cells (based on the assumption that your view will contain the same information for each item/person); each containing a Container View for your different view controllers.

This means you won't have to worry about auto-layout so much and your cells should resize automatically as soon as the content changes.